# WP - Archive.php - Not showing all posts in a category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not finding out why archive.php only shows maximum 10 posts in a category... Could you please help to find where the bug is?

```
        <div id="blogg_header" class="col col-lg-12 col-sm-12"><div class="well">
            <?php if (is_category()) {?>
                    <h1 class="title">Kategori: <i><?php single_cat_title(); ?> </i></h1>
                <?php } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
                    <h2 clss="title"><?php the_time('F, Y'); ?></h2>
                <?php } ?>

        </div></div>

        <div id="blogg_innlegg_left" class="col col-lg-8 col-sm-8"><div class="well">
            <ul>
                    <?php if (have_posts()) :?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <a class id="linkforside" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php get_the_post_thumbnail($header_thumb->ID);?><br/>
                    </a>
                        <p class id="infotekst"><?php the_time('d.m.Y') ?></p>
                                <p class="blogg_innlegg_teksten"><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 250);?></p>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php else : ?>

                    <h2>Ingenting ble funnet.</h2>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div></div>
```

I guess I may need to insert the following:

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=postbypost&limit=none'); ?>
```

Comment: Maybe try to check in Settings -> Reading and set other post counts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was actually true, - problem solved! Thanks :)